# ¿Como consumir una API con REACTJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spa

Tengo una aplicación creada con `reactjs` la cual debo consumir una api que me devuelve x datos. El problema que tengo es que no se como se realiza a través de reactjs, eh revisado por Internet el como hacerlo y eh replicado exactamente lo mismo en mi proyecto pero no me resulta. No se si estaré haciendo algo mal o que me faltaría.

Estoy usando la ultima versión estable de reactjs.

Mi código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { items: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:44308/api/persona')
        .then(result=>result.json())
        .then(items=>this.setState({items}))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {
                         this.state.items.map((item) =>{
                            return(
                                 <li></li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

En primera instancia estaba tratando de renderizar n `<li>` dependiendo de la cantidad de datos que devolviera el json pero ni siquiera me pinta la `<li>` en mi vista... luego probe pintando datos, pero menos me funciono.

Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Comment: La mejor solucion es usar fetch, si es posible usa Redux para almacenar la imformacion y que la reciban los componentes como propiedad es un poco mas complejo pero queda mejor organizado el codigo.

Comment: Sigue el siguiente medium encontraras las mejores formas de consumir un api https://medium.com/@jorge.basilio.94/como-consumir-un-api-en-react-js-ba4130386a61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu código quieres retornar una Array de objetos mediante Fech dentro de una lista en React.

El principal fallo de tu código es no retornar el valor, he editado un poco tu código y te lo dejo por abajó para poder explicarte las diferencias.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const List = (props) => (
    <ul>
        {
            props.items.map((item, i) => {
                return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            })
        }
    </ul>
)

class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { 
            done: false,
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:44308/api/persona')
        .then(result=>result.json())
        .then(items=>this.setState({
            done: true,
            items
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.done && this.state.items.isArray() ? (
                    <List items={...this.state.items} />
                ) : (
                    <p>Cargando resultados...</p>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Lo primero que hemos hecho antes de definir las clase [Component] que se va a exportar como elemento del DOM, es definir un Componente sin estado, el cual será el que nos devuelva la lista con los datos.

```
const List = (props) => (
    <ul>
        {
            props.items.map((item, i) => {
                return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            })
        }
    </ul>
)
```

En cada `<li />` tenemos que definir una key, la cual ayuda a react a no cometer errores a la hora de renderizar los datos de una lista.

En el principal de la clase hemos definido dos variables, las cuales son **Done** que nos ayudará a determinar si la llamada a la API ha sido completada y la variable **items**.

Ahora cuando realizamos la llamada al la API mediante fetch, y esta es exitosa, modificamos las dos variables de estado que habíamos definido en un principio.

> Podemos definir otra variable de estado en caso de que la llamada a la API nos devuelva un .catch(), que podría ser por defecto **success: true** el cual nos ayudaría a solucionar muchos errores que pueden ser producidos, al hacer esto tendríamos que hacer lo siguiente.

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:44308/api/persona')
        .then(result=>result.json())
        .then(items=>this.setState({
            done: true,
            items
        }))
        .catch(() => {
            this.setState({
                done: true,
                success: false
            })
        })
    }
```

Ahora en el método de renderización, lo que hemos evitado es que el usuario vea todo en blanco hasta que la API devuelva los valores mediante la función asincrona fetch.

```
render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.done && this.state.items.isArray() ? (
                    <List items={...this.state.items} />
                ) : (
                    <p>Cargando resultados...</p>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

> Si queremos que en caso de error la aplicación nos devuelva otra cosa podemos hacer lo siguiente

```
render() {
        if(this.state.done) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.done && this.state.success ? (
                            <List items={...this.state.items} />
                        ) : (
                            <p>No se han podido recuperar los datos del servidor</p>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (<p>Cargando contenidos...</p>)
        }
    }
```

Ha partir de este punto es donde entra en función el componente sin estado  que hemos definido al principio del código.

Para que el componente sea funcional tenemos que incluir la variable de estado items en su totalidad usando:

```
<List items={...this.state.items} />
```

Y este realiza toda la lógica de crear las tablas con los valores de la propiedad items.

```
{
    props.items.map((item, i) => {
        return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
    })
}
```

**Espero haberte sido de gran ayudar!!** :D

Answer (score 2):

Según veo en tu código, faltan dos cosas que puede ayudarte a solucionar el error que tienes, te comento:

- En la consulta 'fetch' le falta pasar las opciones indicándole el método que necesitas (GET,POST,...) y la cabecera si la necesitas:

  ```
  fetch('http://localhost:44308/api/persona', {method: 'GET'}) //Ejemplo con 'GET'
    .then(result=>result.json())
    .then(items=>this.setState({items}))
  ```
- Donde se renderiza el Html te falta devolver el item en el 'map':

  ```
  <ul>
      {this.state.items.map( item => <li>{item}</li>)}
  </ul>
  ```

Creo que con estos cambios debería de funcionar, siempre y cuando, recibas la info desde la api.

¿Podrías confirmarlo?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un `console.log` justo antes de pintar el array para el `<li>` :

```
{   
     console.log(this.state.items) ||
     this.state.items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
}
```

De esta forma podrás ver si te están llegando los datos justo antes de recorrerlos.

Answer (score 0):

te creas un type users en tu state

```
this.state= {
      users:[]
    }
```

trabajas en la funcion componentDidMount // para cuando ya se renderiza

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        users:data
      })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
```

y en el render iteras con .map sobre tu arreglo users

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <h1>Messages</h1>
          {this.state.users.map((user) => (
              <div className="user" key={user.login}>
                <div id="outer"></div>
                <div><h5>{user.login} </h5></div>
                <div><button>perfil</button></div>
                <div><button>delete</button></div>
                </div>
              </div>
          ))}
        </div>
    )
  }
```